# Are there any Bitcoin block explorers still around that log First Seen by node data?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, blockchain-explorer

Title..  Hoping to find out when a historical tx went into the mempool.  I'm aware this is transient data and not in the blockchain.  However i'm pretty sure I remember in the old days explorers used to log it.

edit:

i would like to find a block explorer that logs the first time its node saw particular transactions in the mempool, as opposed to the first time they were in a block.   ie:  I would like to look up a tx and see how long it sat in the mempool before it was mined.

Comment: The closest thing i know of is https://mempool.observer/monitor/ but i don't think they store the first seen version of an RBFed tx.

Comment: From my recollection: For transaction in the mempool, a timestamp in a block explorer is set to when the transaction was first observed; once the transaction is mined, the timestamp is changed to the timestamp of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a bit more specific?

There are a few block explorers that do provide information specific to their block explorer's running node.

Best lead I have for you is: https://bitcoinvisuals.com/

There's a lot of node information on there though I'm not sure its exactly what you're looking for.

However, I know that the owner of the site is pretty responsive and very easy to get into contact with.

Comment: I edited my question.